# sqlsrv_connect() not working with Wamp 32 bit

Tags: sql-server, wamp

I am using wamp 32 bit version & have downloaded sql server drivers from Microsoft site as well.

I have added all these in both ini files php & Apache as well,Not sure which one to keep & which one to remove.

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

Still I am getting this error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\wamp\www\otpvoice\db.php on line 25

Comment: What version of PHP are you using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in WAMPServer you need the `Thread Safe` **ts** version of these files and not the `Not Thread Safe` **nts** versions.

Then you need the Thread safe version that matches your PHP Version

So for example this dll is for PHP 5.3

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
```

and this would be for PHP 5.6

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

Comment: :-Thank you for the explanation! It really helped alot to understand the code